# Why Protons travel through the membrance but electrons travel through the wire?

Tags: batteries, electron, electrode

In the case of having two electrodes (anode and cathode). I will always hear that positive ions will jump from one electrode to the other causing the electricity to flow the wire. How come only protons only jump between electrodes and electrons too. Is there a layer that only allows protons to travel? and are there different types of those layers?

Comment: Not that an ion moving is not the same as a proton moving (unless it's hydrogen). Also, I assume you are talking about a battery which you never actually mentioned.

Comment: So it seems the membrane is specfically made to allow positive ions through to neutralize the charge so the battery continues to work, and specifically to block negative ions from passing through (I don't know if this also means it blocks lone electrons ). It's called an "ion exchange membrane" if you want to Google around to try and figure out how it does what it does.

Comment: If an atom gives up an electron, what charge is on the atom?   Only one charge moves. Ions, which have protons, can move.

Comment: Yes, the membrane only allows the protons to travel (e.g. Hydrogen ions). However, I want to know how efficient is the proton transfer. Does the membrane affect the ration of proton transfer? is the membrane performance is based on the material it is made of ? are membranes conductors?